# How to create test users on the localhost?

Tags: users

I would like to make test users on my localhost (in my case I am using WAMP). Since I need to be able to authenticate them via email. I am not getting it to work what can I do?

Comment: you got some advance with your problem?

Comment: Hi, yes, solved it the way by activating the user  in the admin area. By putting the user on 'active' . So email comfirmation is not needed. However the drawback is that you have to log in and log out all the time to test it. I will try one of the module for this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add new user you can go to `admin/people/create` (*localhost/YOUR-SITE/admin/people/create*) and create the user, you don't need to enter a real email. And if you want to test the site with different users you can use the [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) module.

> The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with
>   enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no
>   password required). That person can switch back to their own user
>   account at any time.
>
> This is helpful for site developers when trying to determine what a
>   client, logged in as themselves, might see when logged into the site.

Answer (score 0):

very easy, go to people section and add a new account manually. and change user state to active

Comment: The question contains "***I need to be able to authenticate them via eMail***". Can you update your answer to address that part of the question?

Comment: Actually I found out this works when you login with the created user name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a generic alternative, but I used the [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) when I built my Drupal website on a localhost. Also, if you need to create a lot of test users, the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module can come in handy. After installing it, you can automatically create any number of users with randomly filled in user fields. I am not sure whether the authentication via email will still work in that way, but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like Mailcatcher/Mailhog on your local dev stack, it will catch all outgoing mail instead of actually allow it to be sent to users. You can then log into its admin, and view the emails, and obtain the content/link within.

Dev stacks like drupalvm.com come with this option and is an easy switch on. Test emails to your hearts content.

You don't want to test with a module that does any sort of mail rerouting (all mail goes to user 1 for example) because that isn't really testing in near - real world conditions.